# How to Align text at left from div when tags inside div have inline text-align to justify

Tags: javascript, html, css, model-view-controller, text-align

I want to fix the front view of a website. I am a just a beginner. The issue arising in the long description which having values in p tags.

**laptop View:**

[image]

**Mobile View:**

[image]

**Css in Inspect:** i have no idea from where **Class="MsoNormal" and style** come from in BLDes, but i have to fix it.

[image]

Code Behind:

```
<div class="uni-entry-description" style="text-align:left !important">
                                                        <p>
                                                            @Html.Raw(Model.BLDes)
                                                        </p>
                                                    </div>
```

The value of Model.BLDes is edit my Rich Text Editor. So, it contain some p tag in it. The div inline css is not working in it.

The first p tag in inspect is from code, while other p tags are the value of BLDes.

I used the inline css in div with **!important** keyword but its not working. I also used media query for mobile view but not working.
Thanks for the help in advance.

What I tried so far:

- [Spacing between some words is just too big in mobile view when text is justified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55613780/spacing-between-some-words-is-just-too-big-in-mobile-view-when-text-is-justified)
- [Disable inline css style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34721556/disable-inline-css-style)
- [Remove a specific inline style with Javascript|jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033004/remove-a-specific-inline-style-with-javascriptjquery)

Comment: to overwrite text-align on p from inline style, !important will only work from a style sheet not style from inline parent's style attribute. it won't apply to children where inline style are also set. Javascript can do to . what have you tried that failed ? share your attempts, so we can see why it is failing.

Comment: I used the stylesheet too with !important but nothing is working. i also used important keyword in media query but result is same

Comment: okay, have you  tried JavaScript ? something like : `window.onload=function() {for (let e of document.querySelectorAll(".uni-entry-description p")) {e.style.textAlign ="left";} }` ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone. Who read the post and contribute to it.

The problem is solved by the help of [Remove a specific inline style with Javascript|jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033004/remove-a-specific-inline-style-with-javascriptjquery).


I just change the location of script tag from top to bottom of the page.

```
<script>
    let declaration = document.getElementsByClassName("MsoNormal");
    for (let i = 0; i < declaration.length; i++) {
        declaration[i].style.removeProperty("text-align");
    }    
</script>
```

If someone explains to me why changing the location of script solve the problem, it's really helpful for me in the future. To avoid such mistake. Thanks in advance


[Edited]
Change the above code so any tag not having MsoNormal class still align to left

```
let allElementInDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("uni-entry-description");
    for (let i = 0; i < allElementInDiv[0].children.length; i++) {
        allElementInDiv[0].children[i].style.removeProperty("text-align");
    }
```

Comment: Your script should be loaded after the HTML is loaded else it won't find anything. It can be just before closing the body tag or on window.onload event ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `style="text-align:left"` and try this code

```
<p align="left">
        @html...
</p>
```

Comment: Nothing happened.